# Volume from equation $(x ^2+ y ^2 + z ^2 ) ^2 = xyz$

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, volume

How can you calculate the volume of the shape represented by the following equation: $$(x ^2+ y ^2 + z ^2 ) ^2 = xyz$$
I tried converting it to polar form (so $r = \sin^2\left(\theta\right)\cdot\cos\left(\theta\right)\cdot\sin\left(\phi\right)\cdot\cos\left(\phi\right)$) and integrate over $\phi$ and $\theta$ with range $2\pi$, however, that didn't work out. How can I approach this?

Comment: Is the volume zero, perhaps? Are there any real solutions to this equation other than the trivial $(0,0,0)$?

Comment: @DavidQuinn I don't know

Comment: No, the volume isn't zero, as is obvious from the polar form. The point you might be missing is that only the regions over which $R(\theta, \phi) = \sin^2 \theta \cos \theta \frac{\sin 2\phi}{2} \ge 0$ should be integrated. Consequently, your double integral after integrating over $r$ should break into two parts - $\int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/2} \int_{\phi = 0}^\pi + \int_{\theta = \pi/2}^\pi \int_{\phi = \pi}^{2\pi}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ (x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 = xyz$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} r \cos \varphi \sin \psi \\ r \sin \varphi \sin \psi \\ r \cos \psi \end{pmatrix} $$
$$ r^4 =| r^3 \sin( \varphi) \cos( \varphi) \cos( \psi) \sin^2 (\psi) |$$
$$ r = |\sin( \varphi) \cos( \varphi) \cos( \psi) \sin^2 (\psi)| $$

$${\rm d}V = r^2 \sin(\psi) {\rm d}r {\rm d}\psi {\rm d}\varphi $$

$$ V = \iiint {\rm d}V = \int \limits_0^{2\pi} \int \limits_0^\pi \int_0^{|\sin( \varphi) \cos( \varphi) \cos( \psi) \sin^2 (\psi)|} r^2 \sin\psi\; {\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\psi\,{\rm d}\varphi $$

$$ V = \int \limits_0^{2\pi} \int \limits_0^\pi \frac{\sin\psi}{3} | \sin\varphi \cos\varphi \sin^2 \psi \cos \psi|^3\,{\rm d}\psi\,{\rm d}\varphi \\ = \int \limits_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2\varphi \cos^2\varphi |\sin \varphi \cos \varphi|}{60}\;{\rm d}\varphi$$

According to Wolfram

$$ V = \frac{1}{180}$$

Comment: 1) you computed the volume of $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 = |xyz|$ instead. 2) you forget the factor $\frac{1}{60}$ in your last expression.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it. In spherical coordinates the distance is implicitly considered always positive and thus the absolute value in the expression for $r$.

Comment: Not really, the original equation is in Cartesian coordinate, you should only integrate over the region where $x y z \ge 0 \iff \sin\phi\cos\phi \sin^2\psi \cos\psi \ge 0$. You answer is off by a factor $2$.

Comment: @achillehui Why this $xyz \geq 0$ information is not carried along with the spherical coordinate transformation? It appears some "extra" caution is needed to integrate in the spherical coordinate.

Comment: @Taozi when you allow $r$ to be negative, you coordinate chart cover (nearly) every point twice. In this case, because of the symmetry of the surface, the integral your computed naively over all $(\theta,\phi)$ will be doubled.

Comment: @achillehui But how can $r$, by definition, be negative? Whether in 2D polar coordinate $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ or in 3D $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ it is defined to be positive, it's the distance from the point to origin and distance can only be positive right?